# Align two div's and hr tag for step progress bar

Tags: html, css, frontend, line

I have following progress bar
[image]

1. I want the 'created', 'assigned' div's below circle and centred at the same time 'hr' line should touch the circle. Should work for varying screen sizes
2. How to make perfect circle here?

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div   class="progress">

        <div id='content' class='filledCircle'></div>
          <div>Created</div>
            <hr class="line">
        <div id='content' class='filledCircle'></div>
          <div>Assigned</div>

    </div> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container{
 position: relative;
 border: 3px solid mistyrose;
 margin-left: 50%;

}

.progress{
 display: flex;
}

hr.line{
 border: none;
 background: grey;
 width: 100%;
 height: 2px;
}

.filledCircle{
 height: 25px;
 width: 25px;
 background-color: #bbb;
 border-radius: 50%;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: my answer wasn't useful for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For making a better circle you can use Padding

```css
.container{
 position: relative;
 border: 3px solid mistyrose;
 margin-left: 50%;

}

.progress{
 display: flex;
 align-items:center
}

hr.line{
 border: none;
 background: grey;
 width: 100%;
 height: 2px;
}

.filledCircle{
padding:15px;
 background-color: #bbb;
 border-radius: 50%;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div   class="progress">

        <div id='content' class='filledCircle'></div>
          <div>Created</div>
            <hr class="line">
        <div id='content' class='filledCircle'></div>
          <div>Assigned</div>

    </div> 
</div>
```

Just use `align-items: center` in your CSS file
and use padding instead of width and height

```
.progress {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}

    .filledCircle {
      padding: 15px;
      background-color: #bbb;
      border-radius: 50%;
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

Comment: thanks it worked. how does padding give a circle? if i remove it, wont work!

Comment: if you like this answer please accept it and padding help to have Equal area in all directions @krishna

Comment: ok thanks. but you didnt answer my first question of line touching the circle! i am waiting if anyone answers that

Answer (score 1):

```css
.container{
 position: relative;
 border: 3px solid mistyrose;
 margin-left: 50%;

}

.progress{
 display: flex;
}

hr.line{
 border: none;
 background: grey;
 width: 100%;
 height: 2px;
}

.filledCircle{
 height: 25px;
 width: calc(25px * 2);
 background-color: #bbb;
 border-radius: 50%;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div   class="progress">

        <div id='content' class='filledCircle'></div>
          <div>Created</div>
            <hr class="line">
        <div id='content' class='filledCircle'></div>
          <div>Assigned</div>

    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

I used CSS grids and put the circle, line and text in them and centred them accordingly.

```
display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: [colstart]1fr  [two]1fr [three]2fr [four]1fr [five]1fr [colend];
  grid-template-rows: [rowstart]80% [rowcenter] auto[rowend];
```